# Magento: How do I debug if class_exist

Tags: magento

In Magento I am getting the error

```
'Model class does not exist: Cerulean_School_Model_Observer'
```

However I clearly have the file:

```
$ ls -l app/code/local/Cerulean/School/Model/Observer.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 vyom webuser 877 Oct 24 02:27 app/code/local/Cerulean/School/Model/Observer.php
```

I have no idea on how to debug this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up that file and see if it really states

```
<?php class Cerulean_School_Model_Observer
```

and if it really exists then you can do for testing

```
<?php $test = new Cerulean_School_Model_Observer();
```

and every time you encounter a new framework , app with a structure you should familiarize with naming conventions as a first step that helps you understand the structure

you should follow http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Comment: I see the logic in this. Howevert I had Cerulean_School_Observer class name as per direction as per instructions in  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/affiliate_conversion_tracking_with_multiple_networks.